# how to perform floating point calculation in tmote sky (contiki)

Tags: embedded, msp430, contiki

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h> /* For printf() */

PROCESS(calc_process, "calc process");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&calc_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(calc_process, ev, data)
{
 double  dec=13.2, res=0, div=3.2;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();

res=dec+div;

printf("%f",res);


  PROCESS_END();
}
```

After uploading the above code in Tmote sky platform using the command

make TARGET=sky calc.upload, the program will be loaded to the mote (there is no error). Then login to the mote using make login TARGET=sky, the following output is displayed....

OUPUT:

**Rime started with address 4.0
MAC 04:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 Contiki 2.7 started. Node id is set to 4.
CSMA ContikiMAC, channel check rate 8 Hz, radio channel 26
Starting 'calc process'

%f**

How can I get the correct value?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf support for MSP430 micro-controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545317/printf-support-for-msp430-micro-controller)

Answer (score 0):

It is not floating point calculation support that you need - you have that already.  What is missing is floating point support within `printf()`.  That is to say that `res` will be calculated correctly, but `printf()` does not support its display.

Because it requires a relatively large amount of code, many microcontroller targeted libraries omit floating point support in stdio. There may be a library build option to include floating point support - refer to the library documentation.

You might do well to ask a question about the specific calculation necessary, and how it might be done using integer or fixed point arithmetic.  Alternatively you might write your own floating point display as described here: [How to print floating point value using putchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357212/how-to-print-floating-point-value-using-putchar/4361722#4361722) for example.